# Proper installation of powershell modules for all users

Tags: powershell, module

I've looked at [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/module/installing-a-powershell-module), and it lists `$Env:ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` (`%ProgramFiles%\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`) as a good place for installing modules for all users. About naming, it says:

> Use the Correct Module Directory Name
>
> A "well-formed" module is a module that is stored in a directory that
>   has the same name as the base name of at least one file in the module
>   directory. If a module is not well-formed, Windows PowerShell does not
>   recognize it as a module.
>
> The "base name" of a file is the name without the file name extension.
>   In a well-formed module, the name of the directory that contains the
>   module files must match the base name of at least one file in the
>   module.
>
> For example, in the sample Fabrikam module, the directory that
>   contains the module files is named "Fabrikam" and at least one file
>   has the "Fabrikam" base name. In this case, both Fabrikam.psd1 and
>   Fabrikam.dll have the "Fabrikam" base name.
>
> ```
> C:\Program Files   Fabrikam Technologies
>     Fabrikam Manager
>       Modules
>         Fabrikam
>           Fabrikam.psd1 (module manifest)
>           Fabrikam.dll (module assembly)
> ```

However, I'm still unclear; suppose I have a module composed `ABC.psd1` and `ABC.psm1`. Am I understanding correctly that it should be installed in `$Env:ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ABC`, with the .psd1 and .psm1 directly under that directory?

Looking at some of the microsoft modules, I see, for example:

```
C:\Program Files
    WindowsPowerShell
      Modules
        AzureRM
           5.7.0
              AzureRM[.psd1,psm1]
```

So at least based on the referenced document, it breaks the rule of "well-formed module" since the statement does not seem to allow for that `5.7.0` directory, or does not talk about a recursive search. Is that a hierarchy specifically intended for versioning, is it of the developer's choice? Even for versioning, it doesn't match the recommendations in the above document, for "Using Multiple Versions of a Module" which suggest it is added to the directory name, not as a subdirectory.

The gist of my question is this:

1. Is there a better explanation on how powershell searches for modules in this directory, with respect to nesting?
2. Suppose as my product grows, I have a second module `DEF.psd1`. Should I group under a company or product folder, and will all versions of powershell be happy with this (that is, without me altering the PSModulePath).

e.g.:

```
C:\Program Files
    WindowsPowerShell
          Modules
              My Company
                     ABC
                         ABC[.psd1,psm1]
                     DEF
                         DEF[.psd1,psm1]
```

I am looking to support Powershell 3.0 and later. Also, I am noticing that the powershell ISE module browser uses different rules for searching modules, than powershell itself. For example, using my proposed hierarchy with a company name works fine in powershell, ISE, and user scripts, but breaks the ISE module browser which gives a "cannot find module" error when clicking on "Show details".

Comment: You can version modules.  I would not put them under a `My Company` folder.

Comment: In a PowerShell console, use `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory -Path ${Env:ProgramFiles}\WindowsPowerShell\Modules | ForEach-Object { $_.FullName }`. This shows how modules are typically installed.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Do i version them the way the Microsoft document says, or the way they do it in practice, with a subdirectory?

Comment: @lit that doesn't tell me much, except that putting them under a COmpany folder works on my specific powershell version. However it fails in Powershell ISE's "get details" feature. The browser finds the module and the exposed functions, but fails when I click "Get Details".

Comment: @WillIAm You version them in the manifest file.  If you plan on publishing multiple versions or making it more maintainable, also create a subfolder in the module that matches your manifest `/MyModule/1.0.0.0/MyModule.psd1` or it'll throw an error when you get to deploying/maintaining multiple module versions.

Comment: Thanks. That means use the way the microsoft does it in practice. The document recommends a different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you pretty much have this answered. Not sure why/how the AzureRM module has a versioning folder...but the module was created by Microsoft so maybe they know a loop hole.

In my experience and in the documentation I've read, the proper file structure is what you have in your example, except WITHOUT the 'My Company' folder. How you named the folders and the .psm1/psd1 files (with the same base name) is correct. In fact, for a minimal script based module, all you need is the .psm1 file and it will work (load whatever functions are in the file), although generating a module file with New-ModuleManifest doesn't hurt. As mentioned in the comments, versioning can then be tracked and recognized by PowerShell in the .psd1 file.

Now, I've never put a module in the ProgramFiles folder for all users but I imagine it uses the same rules as the user based folders (they are just paths in an enviroment variable that powershell looks at).

I've also used the link below as a method or template for building PowerShell modules that are easy to maintain:
http://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/Building-A-PowerShell-Module/

You can ignore the parts you aren't interested in or not using (folders for tests or views or using a Git repo)...the base structure works as well as the technique for loading individual functions with the .psm1 file.